# Java file for multi column list

Tags: android

i am creating an app with multiple columns. i tested all the functions for one row and it is working as desired. can I use the same code for the other rows or I have to replicate for the number of rows?

Comment: This question is too ambiguous please expand your question and explanation of what exactly you are trying to do, you should also show any code that you have already created.

Also instead of asking if you can use the same code, why don't you give it a shot and see if it works?

Comment: @Macca thank you, I will try that and see.

Comment: Of course you will make a loop where you iterate through the rows.

Comment: @greenapps can you give an example of the loop? thank you.

Comment: @greenapps hold on with your example.  let me try something , then if it works I will let you  know.